# Visual studio se cierra cuando creo o inicio un programa, pero este no avisa que haya un error

Tags: visual-studio, windows

el problema que tengo es que por alguna razón visual studio se cierra siempre que intento abrir un programa, no avisa de error solo se cierra súbitamente, ya he utilizado esta herramienta antes pero es la primera vez que esto me pasa y no se como solucionarlo, alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: que sistema operativo es?

Comment: El sistema es windows 11

Comment: Que dice el log? tengo entendido que se ubica en `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ActivityLog`